# How to judge the node of json exists

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to Deserialize json string to Object, but I can't judge if the node is `null` or not. eg. `jo["data"]["prevtime"]`, sometimes `json` has the node of `["prevtime"]`, sometimes doesn't have `["prevtime"]`. If `["prevtime"]` is `null`, it will report an error.

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(content);
if (jo["data"].ToString() == "")
    return new StatusCollection();

var jInfo = jo["data"]["info"];
StatusCollection list = new StatusCollection();
Status status = null;

if (jInfo != null)
{
    foreach (var j in jInfo.Children())
    {

       if (jo["data"]["prevtime"] != null) 
       {
           status.Nexttime = jo["data"]["nexttime"].ToString();
           status.Prevtime = jo["data"]["prevtime"].ToString();
       }

       status = j.ToObject<Status>();
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status.Head))
       {
           status.Head += "/50";
       }
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status.From))
       {
           status.From = "来自" + status.From;
       }
       list.Add(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: This line will report error[if (jo["data"]["prevtime"] != null) ] if don't have ["prevtime"] in jo["data"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to select the token you want, and there is a property to get the token value

```
if (jo["data"].Select("prevtime") != null) 
{
        status.Prevtime = jo["data"].Value<string>("prevtime");
        status.Nexttime = jo["data"].Value<string>("nexttime");
}
```

JSON.NET Documentation:

[Link 1](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken_1.htm)

[Link 2](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm)

Answer (score 3):

In the current version, it would be like :

```
if (jo["data"].Select***Token***("prevtime") != null) 
{
        status.Prevtime = jo["data"].Value<string>("prevtime");
        status.Nexttime = jo["data"].Value<string>("nexttime");
}
```